# Server location in linux machine?

Tags: java, linux, jboss

Where in the linux machine we will install servers(Jboss fuse, data virtualization, jboss and all) is it in the root directory or in home directory ?

Comment: you can install things anywhere you want. good luck making it work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no universally accepted standard, but `/opt` is probably the most common place to install software packages that aren't part of the distribution's package repositories.